# Calculating residua of $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^3(1-z\operatorname{ctg}z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Calculating residua of $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^3(1-z\operatorname{ctg}z)}$. 
Lets define the solutions of $z=\operatorname{tg}z$ as $\lambda_i\:,i\in \mathbb{Z}$.
Its easy to see that poles of $f$ are $0$ and $\lambda_i$. Now my question is how can I evaluate residua of $f$ at $\lambda_i$. I think $\lambda_i$ are poles of order $1$.  From wikipedia residuum is equal to:
$$\lim_{z\to\lambda_i}\frac{z-\lambda_i}{z^3(1-z\operatorname{ctg}z)}$$

So I guess my question comes to calculating this limit. Should I try to expand denominator in Laurent series around $\lambda_i$? At $0$ it is easy, because expansion is known.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I need, but would like to know how to derive it also.

Comment: Sorry, made a silly typo. Write the series expansion for $1 - z \cot z$ and simplify using the equation on $\lambda_i$. Then take the reciprocal series and multiply by the series for $1/z^3$:
$$1 - z \cot z = \lambda_i (z - \lambda_i) + O(|z - \lambda_i|^2), \\
\frac 1 {1 - z \cot z} \frac 1 {z^3} =
\left( \frac 1 {\lambda_i (z - \lambda_i)} + O(1) \right)
 \left( \frac 1 {\lambda_i^3} + O(|z - \lambda_i|) \right).$$